# Baggage Allowance with Qatar Economy (N) class?

Tags: luggage, regulations, munich, qatar-airways, bangalore

I am confused on Qatar Baggage Allowance, my onward journey from India to Germany was 30K with class Economy / O and my return from Germany to India Economy / N Class and baggage allowance mentioned was 45KG.

1. Can i plan my baggage as per details mentioned in my Ticket?
2. Or i should stick to only 30KG as per details mentioned in Qatar Website.

> For bookings made from 18th April, 2016 onwards. Prior bookings for flights originating from Africa have a checked baggage allowance of 50kg (110lb) for First Class, 40kg (88lb) for Business Class and 30kg (66lb) for Economy Class.
>   Maximum dimension = length + width + height
>   Baggage allowances may vary according to route and cabin class. Please check the exact baggage regulations printed on your ticket.
>   Excess baggage charges may apply if you exceed the weight and/or piece allowances. Contact your local Qatar Airways office for more information.
>   A single piece of checked baggage must not weigh more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down such that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).

Tried ending up contacting Local Qatar office and finally writing here for some help.

Comment: Are you planning to buy 15 kg worth of stuff in Germany to bring home?  Unless I am traveling for work with a lot of tour gear, I never reach my weight limit with clothing and personal items.

Comment: i have some official stuff to carry along wid me including my clothes and personal things... off course some chock;s :P So i want to plan accordingly..!!

Comment: Not sure what "chock;s" are, my point was if you leave home with less than 30kgs, do you think you will come home with much more?  But if Qatar issued your ticket and they stated on the ticket 45kg for the return, then you get 45 kg.

Comment: I'll upvote if you bring 15kg of chocolates :-)

Comment: @Dorothy i have only 31KG and i worried for the extra 1KG which i was exeeded. Anyways. Qatar has confirmed that i am eligible for 45KG of which i am using only 31KG. Hope this may help some one..!!!

Comment: A flight between Germany and India is not a flight "originating from Africa," so the change mentioned in the paragraph you quote does not apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information given on your tickets is accurate. If the ticket says 30, it's 30. If it says 45, it's 45. Any weight exceeding that will have to be paid for or removed.

Practically, what this means for you is that you can carry more on the way back than you can on the way out. I guess you will be able to bring a lot of souvenirs if you want to.

Adding @Willeke's comment to the answer: Most airports have an upper limit of 32 kg max per item, I do not remember any that exceed that. It is in EU law that workers do not have to lift more than that even with two people working. 45 kg has to be in two items of luggage.